# Ошибка с динамической матрицей

Tags: c, динамические-массивы, матрицы, malloc

Скажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?
Нужно ввести и вывести матрицу, всё.

```
int main()
{
    int* matr;
    int n,m;

    scanf("%i",&n);
    scanf("%i",&m);

    matr = malloc(m*n*sizeof(int));

    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            scanf("%i",&matr[j,i]);
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            printf("%2i",matr[j,i]);
        }
        puts("");
    }

    return 0;
}



Ввод: 
3 3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

Вывод: 
7 8 9
7 8 9
7 8 9
```

UPD:

```
int printline(int* line){
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        printf("%2i ",line[i]);
    }
}
```

Ввод :

```
3 4
2 1 0
3 5 6
7 9 8
1 5 2
```

Вывод :

```
5 6 -1414812757
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте я лучше покажу, как:

```
int main()
{
    int** matr;
    int n,m;

    scanf("%i",&n);
    scanf("%i",&m);

    matr = malloc(m*sizeof(int*));
    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
        matr[j] = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            scanf("%i",&matr[j][i]);
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            printf("%2i",matr[j][i]);
        }
        puts("");
    }

}
```

Только по-хорошему, надо еще и выделенную память освобождать.

Comment: Допустим, а почему у меня не правильно, ведь по логике правильно

Comment: @buciki вот так считывайте и аналогично выводите scanf("%i",&matr[j*m + i]); (https://ideone.com/45dHC0)

Comment: Неправильно. Хотя бы потому, что `[j,i]` означает по сути `[i]` - почитайте учебники...

Comment: @Harry Хорошо, смотрите, а вот как передать и обработать строку матрицы в функции? Передаю так `myfunc(matr[2]) //3-ая строка`, затем, в функции обращаюсь к элементу так `printf("%i ",line[1]) //2-ой элемент`, но к сожалению ошибка

Comment: `void myfunc(int*a){ printf("%i",a[1]); }` - функция, `myfunc(matr[2])` - вызов (имею в вижу `matr`, описанную в моем коде).

Comment: @Harry Ну вот посмотрите, я обновил тему, вызываю функцию `&(matr[1])` и выводит чуть не то

Comment: https://ideone.com/5KrNGL Ну вы как издеваетесь - меняете в цикле `j`, а выводите `line[i]`... Вы что, сами это не увидели?